# Unable to insert data to a table with FK's using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, blazor

I am very new to Entity Framework and currently using it with a Blazor project I am doing.  So far I have managed to insert basic data (id, name) on multiple models with no problem.
Now I am trying to bring them together.  I have followed the guide from Microsoft and added the navigation properties between the model that need to be joined.  I have checked the actual database and can see all the tables and FKs are correct.  However, when I try to insert, I can see in the Output that it is trying to insert to the tables the FKs are referencing, which results in the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Developers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I have looked around and re read the guide but nothing really explains what is happening.

Game.cs

```
public class Game
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Difficulty { get; set; }
        public double HoursToComplete { get; set; }
        public DateTime Added { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime? Started { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StoryCompleted { get; set;}
        public DateTime? PlatinumAchieved { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Abandoned { get; set; }
        public Status Status => FetchStatus();

        public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
        public Developer Developer { get; set; }
        public List<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
        public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        private Status FetchStatus()
        {
            if(Abandoned.HasValue)
                return Status.Abandoned;

            if(PlatinumAchieved.HasValue)
                return Status.PlatinumAchieved;

            if(StoryCompleted.HasValue)
                return Status.StoryCompleted;

            if (Started.HasValue)
                return Status.Playing;

            return Status.New;
        }
    }
```

Developer.cs

```
public class Developer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    }
```

Not sure if this is a cause but this is how I manipulate the Game object on the Razor Component before calling the add method

```
game.Developer = Developer;
        game.Publisher = Publisher;
        game.Platforms = SelectedPlatforms;
        game.Genres = SelectedGenres;
```

EDIT

This is the output

```
INSERT INTO [Developers] ([Id], [Name])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
INSERT INTO [Genres] ([GenreId], [GenreName])
VALUES (@p2, @p3);
INSERT INTO [Platforms] ([PlatformId], [Name])
VALUES (@p4, @p5);
INSERT INTO [Publishers] ([Id], [Name])
VALUES (@p6, @p7);
INSERT INTO [Games] ([Abandoned], [Added], [DeveloperId], [Difficulty], [HoursToComplete], [Name], [PlatinumAchieved], [PublisherId], [Started], [StoryCompleted])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
VALUES (@p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17);
```

The first 4 inserts should not be happening.  The only thing that should be happening is an insert into Games whichwill also insert into GamesGenres and GamesPlatforms

Comment: Don't set Developer.Id.  Instead just set Name and call SaveChanges.  The database will assign the Id, and you can read it after SaveChanges.

Comment: I can insert into the developer table using this model when I actually want to add a new Developer record.  When I try to insert the Game record, I want it to insert the FK id into the game table.  It may be doing this, but before that INSERT, I see it tries to INSERT into the developers table like I am adding a new record.

Comment: When you attach an entity its state is Added, which will cause an INSERT on SaveChanges.  If you already have that Developer in the database, you may need to change its state to Unchanged.  Read about Change Tracking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/